# How to keep the random moving enemies inside the screen in pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, pygame

I want to keep the enemies (red rectangles in my case) inside the rectangle.What happens is that since it's a random function , the enemies keep on moving.But slowly some of my enemies moves outside , I don't want this to happen.I want them to be inside the screen only.
I have tried subtracting the screen width and screen height but was unsuccessful in my attempt to do so.So basically what  I am asking is how do I check if rectangle is inside the screen.

## EDIT :

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729538/pygame-character-goes-off-screen) is not a possible duplicate as my enemies are moving randomly.In that the player is controlled by the user whereas my program , the movements of the enemy are totally random.

Here is my random movement for my enemies:

```
def evilMove(evilGuy):
    evilCoords = []
    #Returns either -1, 0 or 1
    randomMovex=random.randrange(-1,2)
    randomMovey=random.randrange(-1,2)
    evilMake={'x':evilGuy[0]['x']+randomMovex,'y':evilGuy[0]['y']+randomMovey}


    del evilGuy[-1] #Delete the previous spawn of enemy so there is no trail
    evilCoords.append(evilMake['x']) #Adds x coordinate
    evilCoords.append(evilMake['y']) #Adds y coordinate
    deadZones.append(evilCoords) #Adds the enemy coordinates in the list

    evilGuy.insert(0,evilMake)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729538/pygame-character-goes-off-screen) ?

Comment: why not testing if the new position is inside or outside the screen before moving ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should really look at other questions similar to this, but you could make an if statement where you test if it is outside the screen. 
Lets just say your screen is 500 by 500, you would do,

```
if coordinatesx < 500:
    do this and that
if coordinatesy < 500:
    do this and that.
```

This checks if the coordinates of your bad guy are being checked by the screen by saying if the bad guys coordinates are not larger than the screen, then do what you need to do.

EDIT _________________________________________

```
def evilMove(evilGuy):
    evilCoords = []
    #Returns either -1, 0 or 1
    if x < 500 and y < 500:
    randomMovex=random.randrange(-1,2)
    randomMovey=random.randrange(-1,2)
    evilMake={'x':evilGuy[0]['x']+randomMovex,'y':evilGuy[0]['y']+randomMovey}
```

Im not sure what your x and y variable is called, just replace it with that. And replace the 500 with  your sreen width.